# OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread AWS

Tags: hibernate, grails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, out-of-memory

My Grails application is deployed in Tomcat 6 in AWS EC2 instance. The problem that I am having is that it cannot start and kept on getting the error: OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread. When I ran VisualVM, it seems that a lot of threads were created, around 1,000+. I'm not quite familiar in using this tool and cannot seem to determine at which part of my code creates so much thread. One thing That I have noticed is that when I disabled hibernates 2nd level cache or changed net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider to net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider, the number of threads significantly decreased. Is there a tool that can basically help me in determining where in my code causes the massive increase in creation of threads?

Comment: Are you using elastic beanstalk?

Answer (score 0):

The [yourkit java profiler](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/) does a decent job of showing the stack. NewRelic does too. There are some poorly maintained things like the [Grails Profiler plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/profiler).

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase your memory setting. Go into `bin/setclasspath.sh` of your tomcat and append the following line to the end:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx1024m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

I use this for a pretty big app, so you might be able to run your memory settings to something like:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx512m  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

But it depends on the size of your app.